# After Drupal site migration login stopped working

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I migrated a Drupal 7 site. After successfully migrating the login stopped working. I believe the previous owners used ajax for login. The site works fine but I keep getting an ajax error when trying to login.

```html
Ajax error
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"sparkly","theme_token":"bzLLfcRfRiocJx3GDZ0v8146Ktfuo0YMfghj8B5678","js":{"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/js\/ajax-responder.js":1}},"better_exposed_filters":{"datepicker":false,"slider":false,"settings":[]},"chosen":{"selector":"","minimum_single":25,"minimum_multiple":25,"minimum_width":800,"options":{"disable_search":false,"disable_search_threshold":1,"search_contains":false,"placeholder_text_multiple":"Choose some options","placeholder_text_single":"Choose an option","no_results_text":"No results match","inherit_select_classes":true}},"urlIsAjaxTrusted":{"\/browse":true},"jquery_ajax_load":{"trigger":".jquery_ajax_load\r","target":"#jquery_ajax_load","toggle":1,"animation":0,"base_path":"\/","module_path":"sites\/all\/..."validateOnSubmit":"1","showMessages":"0","errorElement":"span"},"rules":{"name":{"required":true,"messages":{"required":"Username or e-mail address field is required.","maxlength":"Username or e-mail address field has to have maximum 254 values."},"maxlength":254}}}},"general":{"usexregxp":0,"months":{"January":1,"Jan":1,"February":2,"Feb":2,"March":3,"Mar":3,"April":4,"Apr":4,"May":5,"June":6,"Jun":6,"July":7,"Jul":7,"August":8,"Aug":8,"September":9,"Sep":9,"October":10,"Oct":10,"November":11,"Nov":11,"December":12,"Dec":12}},"groups":{"user-pass":{}}}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":"head","data":"\u003Cscript…
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Drush also keeps giving me this error: 
"Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error."

Comment: Is the SMTP host working and accessible by the new location?

Comment: Yes, SMTP module is buggy. When SMTP server account data is not correct it can cause much trouble. Experienced that few times. Set up correct SMTP account info or just disable the module until you get correct data (Drupal will use standard PHP mail function then).

Comment: Yes thank you, @MilanG I figured it out. I realized it was calling the wrong smtp host. Changing the email and host info did the trick.